# How to reinitialize SIM card from application?

Tags: java, android, gsm, javacard

I have a problem writing application for android phone. I need my app to reinitialize all data from SIM card onto a phone - so it would be like a restart without a restart of the phone itself.

I know that going to plane mode and back does not help - it has to be like the real restart. How can I achive it from the app?

Comment: What type of app are you writing that would possibly need this?

Comment: @GabeSechan: I'm writing an app that is making change to the sim card. Right now I have to restart the phone to see the changes working on the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way, but you can always use the SIM Toolkit and proactive commands. According to the [GSM specification](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/11/1114/05.02.00_60/gsmts_1114v050200p.pdf)

> REFRESH,  which  requests  the  ME  to  carry  out  a  SIM  initialization  according  to  GSM 11.11
>   subclause  11.2.1,  and/or  advises  the  ME  that  the  contents  or  structure  of  EFs  on  the  SIM  have
>   been changed. 
>   The command also makes it possible to restart a card session by resetting the SIM.

Description of the REFRESH command, mode SIM Reset:

> SIM  Reset.  This  mode  causes  the  ME  to  run  the  GSM  session  termination  procedure  and  to
>   deactivate  the  SIM  in  accordance  with  GSM  11.11  [20].  Subsequently,  the  ME  activates  the  SIM
>   again  and  starts  a  new  card  session.  In  case  of  a  3  Volt  technology  ME,  the  ME  shall  restart  the
>   SIM with the same supply voltage as in the previous session, if the ME can ensure that the SIM has
>   not  been  changed  in  between.  Otherwise,  the  ME  shall  perform  the  supply  voltage  switching  in
>   accordance  with  GSM  11.12  [21].  The  SIM  Reset  mode  is  used  when  a  SIM  application  requires
>   ATR or complete SIM initialization procedures to be performed.

However, this means you have to have a custom SIM Toolkit applet loaded on the SIM card and you have to use this applet to trigger the proactive command. I don't know if this is a possible option for you, because you didn't provide enough details.

Comment: Thanks vojta.
I will investigate this further. Might be I will need some change in sim card itself, but I guess it would be good way to go as it won't be platform depandant.

Still, for the time being, I'm looking for an easier way to do it on Android, even if it means that it won't be so versatile.